# Access mysql from another computer connected with crossover cable

Tags: mysql, ping, ethernet, crossover

I have two computers, and i am trying to access mysql via network on port 3322 (mysql listens on this port)

Computer A Server:
Windows 10 home
Added firewall exception to port 3322  (mysql installed and listens on this port)
Static IP address: 192.168.0.1
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
connected via onboard ethernet port

Computer B Client:
Windows 10 home
Static IP address: 192.168.0.3
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
connected via usb-to-ethernet port (does not have onboard ethernet)

Both are on the same workgroup, Workgroup
Both computers are connected via a crossover cable (tested ok with cable tester)

First

"B" pinging "A" or vice versa results in "request timed out"

"A" can ping itself & 127.0.0.1

"B" can ping itself & 127.0.0.1

Second

Mysql cannot connect since both computers don't seem to see each other

Comment: I haven't heard of a "crossover cable" since the early days of Windows (in the 90's).  Use Ethernet if you can.

Comment: A USB-Ethernet thingie probably works just like native Ethernet.

Comment: how does Ethernet (you mean straight cable) work for just two computer connected via crossover cable

Comment: Better yet, get a cheap hub (or switch) and use two straight-through cables.

Answer (score 0):

> connected with crossover cable

A crossover cable should work between any two computer (or like devices). Most often today, a straight cable also works, due to the near ubiquity of Auto MDI-X.

If the link comes up on plugging in you're good to go.

> Static IP address: 192.168.0.1 Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0 connected via onboard ethernet port [...] Computer B Client: Windows 10 home Static IP address: 192.168.0.3 Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0

That's a valid IP configuration.

> "B" pinging "A" or vice versa results in "request timed out"

If you haven't configured a firewall permission for ICMP echo that is to be expected. By default, ICMP echo isn't permitted on Windows.

> Mysql cannot connect since both computers don't seem to see each other

If mysql is actually listing on that port (the standard port is 3306) and you've whitelisted it correctly then it should be working. Whether `ping` works is irrelevant.

What *is* relevant is that ARP is working. You can check that by running `arp -a` right after a connection or ping attempt. If ARP isn't working then either the link or your IP config is faulty. Then, if mysql doesn't connect either the firewall config or the mysql config is faulty - run `netstat -aon` to check the latter.